# Find the dimensions of the rectangle of maximum perimeter of an ellipse

Tags: calculus, conic-sections

`A rectangle is inscribed in the ellipse x^2/400 + y^2/225 = 1 with its sides parallel to the axes of the ellipse
(Figure Q5). Find the dimensions of the rectangle of maximum perimeter which can be so inscribed.`

How do i find the dimensions of the rectangle of maximum perimeter.
I honestly have no clue where i should start, It would be really helpful if someone can provide a step-by-step for this solution. (The question and diagram is linked below)

Thanks in advance

[Question & Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXNbg.jpg)

Comment: What have you tries so far?

Comment: Look at the problem in the first quadrant.

Comment: Take a look at this similar problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1542234/how-do-i-find-the-maximum-perimeter-of-a-rectangle-inscribed-in-an-ellipse